# Search posts by ID in admin

Tags: admin, search

I'm looking for a way to search through posts by ID, preferably with support for custom post types. I was hoping there'd be a plugin enabling this functionality, but I've failed to find anything. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean search by ID, every post has a unique ID, how could this search possibly yield any more than a single result?

Comment: @t31os A single result is what I want :). I am referring to being able to seach posts by ID in the admin backend. If you go to http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php you have a search field at the top, and you can easily locate a post by searching through the post titles. I need to be able to do the same, but using IDs. Say, enter '1343', press 'search', get post #1343.

Comment: how does it work for frontend search?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure i understand why you'd want to query by ID, but that said it's possible in a hacky kind of way(i like this method because it's simple).

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'idsearch' );
function idsearch( $wp ) {
    global $pagenow;

    // If it's not the post listing return
    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow )
        return;

    // If it's not a search return
    if( !isset( $wp->query_vars['s'] ) )
        return;

    // If it's a search but there's no prefix, return
    if( '#' != substr( $wp->query_vars['s'], 0, 1 ) )
        return;

    // Validate the numeric value
    $id = absint( substr( $wp->query_vars['s'], 1 ) );
    if( !$id )
        return; // Return if no ID, absint returns 0 for invalid values

    // If we reach here, all criteria is fulfilled, unset search and select by ID instead
    unset( $wp->query_vars['s'] );
    $wp->query_vars['p'] = $id;
}
```

All you then do is search using the regular search box using a `#`(hash) prefix infront of the numeric ID.

```
#123
```

..would return the post with an ID of 123.

I'm sure there's more complicated routes that could be taken to do this, but i don't see any issues with this approach, unless you have lots of posts with titles that start with a hash(but you could always swap the hash for another character).

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: @t310s this works, thank you so much! the only (though purely cosmetic) issue I get is that at the top of the search results I'm getting: Search results for “” — while Search results for “#123” would be ideal. Otherwise this is exactly what I needed, thanks again.

Comment: That's an unfortunate side-effect of unsetting the search terms just before the query, but now i've had another look at edit.php i can see an easy fix... :) Update the `unset()` call to the following.. `unset( $wp->query_vars['s'], $_GET['s'] );` and the search term text will disappear when doing the ID search.. p.s. happy to help.. :)

Comment: Very late in the day but I stumbled across this post and it is possible to re-populate the Search results for... by hooking into the `get_search_query` filter. `add_filter( 'get_search_query', function() { return $_GET['s']; } );`