# Search by post id in a specific page then auto-redirect to searched post

Tags: wp-query, search

I want to be able to search posts by id only in a specific page then automatically redirect users to the searched post. I've found [Search Using Post ID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26589/search-using-post-id) answer, which still works. I've also found [How to redirect search result page to post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128577/how-to-redirect-search-result-page-to-post) which completes my function requirement.

What I want is to combine both and make this whole functionality unique to page id 4629 and **not throughout** the site's search. Is this possible? How do I achieve that?

Here's what I tried to make this unique to the page so far:

I've added `is_page(4629)` after `is_search()` in the first snippet but when tested returns no search results. I've also tried wrapping both snippets with `if(is_page(4629))` around them, then around each of them but that didn't get any search results too.

Thanks

Comment: It's possible. What have you done by far to that effect and what challenge are you facing?

Comment: I'm new to this so my trials may not be sensible to you. I tried to wrap the whole thing like `if(is_page(4629))` but it didn't work. I've also tried adding `&& is_page(4629)` after the `is_search()`. Nothing worked for me.

Comment: Do update your post with that detail as well as the error(s) you are getting. Please note that this medium is NOT for tutorial but to assist developers and or learners, with conscious effort when facing a challenge in their line of duty. New to coding? Take a step at a time and don't bite more than you can chew; hire a developer as you learn and grow with time. All the same, just demonstrate you are putting in as much effort to achieve; not to be freely fed, and the community will gladly assist you.